# Can I execute a cmd command through java?

Tags: java, cmd, execute

I am making a program that needs some of the Java libraries installed already into the computer and also the "classpath" environment variable to be set.

I want to run the set classpath command. Can I do it through java? Or do I need to do something else? Any Example?

Comment: You can use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("<command>")` to execute commandline commands. But i'm not sure if this is really what you want to do..

Comment: try java -classpath .;myjar.jar;lib/referenced-class.jar my.package.MainClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set a system property, you can use [System.setProperty(key,value)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I think that was what I needed-So I know now that Environment variables can be changed without running cmd command in Java.Thanks

Comment: Just know that these properties are *not* global. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/908965/226449

Comment: Do you mean the environment variable that i have changed won't have a changed value in another program that I later or in parallel run on that machine?What about if I have multiple threads in a process?Will it be working there too?

Comment: Another JVM/process will not have the changed value, correct. Within the same process (i.e. another thread) it will show the changed value.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.  Here's are some examples to show you how to do it:

http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

http://www.ehow.com/way_5660016_java-runtime-exec-tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        if (args == null || (args != null && args.length != 1)) 
        {
        System.out.println("Please provide a command");
        }
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`set.exe` is a program like any other. You can start it with [Runtime.exec()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29).