# Singleton class with several different classloaders

Tags: java, singleton, classloader

E.g I have class `Singleton` with static field `instance`:

```
public class Singleton {

    private static Singleton instance;

    // other code, construct, getters, no matter    
}
```

I can load this class twice with two different classloaders. How could I avoid it? It is unsafe and dangerous.

Also, if I set instance to null, would it set to null for both classes?

```
Singleton singleton = Singleton.getInstance();
singleton = null;
```

Comment: If you really want to achieve a singleton design pattern, then follow [enum type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#The_Enum_way) in Java - "*a single-element enum type is the best way to implement a singleton*"

Comment: the enum pattern would not prevent the presence of one instance per class loader, would it?

Comment: Unfortunately enums can be by different classloaders, which as you can imagine can cause all sort of problems.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want a true `Singleton` across classloaders, then you need a common parent to load the class in question, or you need to specify the classloader yourself.

**Update:** From the comment from @Pshemo below a fair bit of the content in the blog below might come directly from a [JavaWorld Article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html).  I've left the blog entry in as it may still help someone, but its worth knowing where the content originally came from.

**Original:**
There is a [blog](http://snehaprashant.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/singleton-pattern-in-java.html) entry that gives you a way to do this"  (although I havent tried it!), and it looks fairly reasonable

As requested below here a  code snippet from my link above - I do suggest you visit the blog though for the full context:

```
private static Class getClass(String classname) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    if(classLoader == null) 
        classLoader = Singleton.class.getClassLoader();
      return (classLoader.loadClass(classname));
}
```

Comment: Nice answer! It would be even better if you included a code example of the solution here, with credit to the linked article.

Comment: How does this code actually help?  How will this be invoked to make sure that the singleton remains a singleton across ClassLoaders?

Comment: There is one more very good web resource to understand this issue. https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2005/08/24/how-single-can-your-singleton-instance-be

Comment: Are you sure that Sneha is the author of that post (or at least part about class loaders)? From what I see linked post was published `8 JANUARY 2009` but it looks the same as part of quite old [article from javaworld](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html) published `Apr 25, 2003`. Post on blog contains even sentence "*The preceding method can be used instead of `Class.forName()`*" which seems out of context because there is no `Class.forName()` method used anywhere earlier, while it makes sense in javaworld since Example 10 uses reflection.

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks for that - I've updated my answer to reflect the likely original source

Comment: Here is a Internet Archive Wayback Machine link for the defunct java.net blog URL provided by @AnkitKumar: https://web.archive.org/web/20051117213814/http://weblogs.java.net:80/blog/kirillcool/archive/2005/08/how_single_is_y.html.  This author is Kirill Grouchnikov and the title is "How single can your singleton instance be?"

Comment: where should i put this method, who will invoke it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a hack misusing the fact that `Properties` extends `Map`, an old unfortunate design decision.

```
public final class JvmWideSingleton
{
    private static final JvmWideSingleton INSTANCE;

    static {
        // There should be just one system class loader object in the whole JVM.
        synchronized(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()) {
            Properties sysProps = System.getProperties();
            // The key is a String, because the .class object would be different across classloaders.
            JvmWideSingleton singleton = (JvmWideSingleton) sysProps.get(JvmWideSingleton.class.getName());

            // Some other class loader loaded JvmWideSingleton earlier.
            if (singleton != null) {
                INSTANCE = singleton;
            }
            else {
                // Otherwise this classloader is the first one, let's create a singleton.
                // Make sure not to do any locking within this.
                INSTANCE = new JvmWideSingleton();
                System.getProperties().put(JvmWideSingleton.class.getName(), INSTANCE);
            }
        }
    }

    public static JvmWideSingleton getSingleton() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

This could be made parametrized, but then the initialization would be lazy and go to `getSingleton()`.

`Properties` is `Hashtable`-based, so it is thread safe (as per the documentation). So one could use `props.computeIfAbsent()`. But I like it this way more.

Also read here: [Scope of the Java System Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908903/scope-of-the-java-system-properties)

I just wrote it and there is a chance there's something I overlooked that would prevent this from working.

Comment: One bug in there... fixing

Comment: It will be create a real singleton, but depending on your use case it won't work because you will get `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class somepackage.config.Config cannot be cast to class somepackage.config.Config` cause the same class on different classloaders is a different class. So depending on the use case people want one singleton per classloader as the jvm default.