# Singleton: Throwing exception in constructor

Tags: java, reflection, singleton

In order to prevent Singleton from being broken by using reflection one way is to throw an exception in private constructor as shown in code below:

```
public final class Foo {

    private static final Foo INSTANCE = new Foo();

    private Foo() {
        if (INSTANCE != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Already instantiated");
        }
    }

    public static Foo getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Above is a standard code but what i am thinking is that is it thread safe? If multiple threads try to create the instance using reflection at same time [i.e. before the class is loaded in main memory which implies instance will be null ] then will they succeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the static members of a class (whether directly or through reflection) before it is loaded. And static final members are initialised during the loading process ([step 9 of the JLS description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)).

So in your case there is no way a thread could:

- see `INSTANCE` before it is properly constructed.
- see `INSTANCE` as null (unless the first call to `new Foo()` throws an exception)
- initialise a second instance (unless that code relies on [a different class loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156840/singleton-class-with-several-different-classloaders))

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create a reflection-safe singleton is to use an enum.
[It is described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)

Comment: i know that but my question is about this method :)

Comment: then I did not understand your question ;-)