# Design patterns - Singleton and class loaders

Tags: java, design-patterns

The Head First design patterns book mentions singletons and class loaders.

> Question : What about class loaders? I heard there is a chance that
>   two class loaders could each end up with their own instance of
>   Singleton.
>
> Answer : Yes, that is true as each class loader defines a namespace.
>   If you have two or more class loaders, you can load the same class
>   multiple times (once in each classloader). Now, if that class happens
>   to be a Singleton, then since we have more than one version of the
>   class, we also have more than one instance of the Singleton. So, if
>   you are using multiple classloaders and Singletons, be careful. One
>   way around this problem is to specify the classloader yourself.

In which situation do Java developers need to have multiple class loaders ? In which situations would multiple class loaders be a problem for singletons ?

Comment: Middle ware applications frequently have multiple class loaders. In the situation that multiple applications are deployed with dependencies that conflict with those provided by an application server; more commonly, application A includes `apache-log4j-2.13.1` - application B includes `apache-log4j-2.10` and the application server includes `apache-log4j-2.9` (I made the version numbers up). The application server "wins". Note this book is now outdated, as Java 9 introduces modules and obviates this kind of dependency management.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I've never come across a system like that. Do you have any non-esoteric examples?

Comment: Depends on how you define esoteric. You can [write your own `ClassLoader`](https://www.journaldev.com/349/java-classloader#java-custom-classloader-example), perhaps because you need to [manipulate bytecode](https://asm.ow2.io/). If your application does not use multiple classloaders, why are you worried about it? Also, the most common way to implement a `Singleton` these days is an `enum` (as I said, that book is a bit outdated).

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533902/java-singleton-usage-with-multiple-class-loaders