# Static variable isolation with Custom Class loader

Tags: java

I have this code

```
        MyClassloader loader = new MyClassloader();
        Class c = loader.loadClass(classToLoad);
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader);
        MyClass myClass = (MyClass) c.newInstance();
```

And classloader code is

```
public MyClassloader) throws IOException {
    super(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
}
```

The class loading works fine the problem is that static variables are not isolated, so if inside the `MyClass` a static variable is set all other `MyClass` instances get the same value.

**In what can a static variable be isolated?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Singleton class with several different classloaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156840/singleton-class-with-several-different-classloaders)

Comment: @MohammedHousseynTaleb That question is the opposite of this question.

Answer (score 3):

You delegate to the same class loader. So you will see no difference.

What should yo do? **Implement** class loading in your class loader, don't just delegate. For instance, inherit your class loader from URLClassLoader, initialize it properly (it means, provide a valid class path to your class loader to initialize it). Then you will see, that classes loaded by you class loader are not euqal to the classes loaded by the standard class loader, and as a consequence, their static members will be different.

Often the context class loader is inherited from URLClassLoader and thus you don't have to spend much time configuring class path for it. Instead, to initialize you class loader you can just reuse the URLs of the context class loader, as follows:

```
public class MyIndependentClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {
  public MyIndependentClassLoader(){
    super(((URLClassLoader) Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()).getURLs());
  }
}
```

Now you can use your class loader and check static members.

What is the difference between this approach and the original approach?

You know that classes are also objects (of special type): they have their own member variables, `name, serialVersionUID, annotationData,` etc., and their own methods, `newInstance(), getFields(), getMethods(),` etc. When you call

```
Class c = loader.loadClass("com.my.package.MyClassX");
```

you get `c`, this is an object that describes the loaded class "some class name". This `c` not only allows to create instances, but holds also all static members.

**In your code:** Your class loader *does not* load class directly. Instead, it delegates to the context class loader. That's why if you compare two loaded classes

```
Class c = loader.loadClass("com.my.package.MyClassX");
Class ct = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass("com.my.package.MyClassX");
```

you will see, that `c` and `ct` is the same object. If you call `c.equals(ct)`, it will give you `true`. And if you call `c == ct`, it will also give you `true`. It means, this is `the same` class instance. That's why - naturally - if you check static variables, they will be the same. If you change static variable in one class, it will also be changed in another class, and vice versa.

**In my code:** The essential difference is, that the class loader loads classes itself. It *does not delegate* it to other class loader. I suggested to extend it from `URLClassLoader` to simplify our implementation (otherwise you would have implement from scratch dealing with class path, directories, jars, visibility, caching, etc.).  And to avoid adding each class path element step by step I suggested to use the same class path (the same list of directories, jars, etc.) as the context class loader. So our class loader will be able to find the same classes as the context class loader.
Now check the class that this class loader loads. Let's call it `ci`:

```
Class ci = new MyIndependentClassLoader().loadClass("com.my.package.MyClassX");
```

If you compare these classes, you will see that `c.equals(ci)` gives `false`. Means, they are *different*. That's why they have also *independent* static members. If you change static member in one class, `ct`, it will not change in the other, `ci`, and vice versa.

Comment: What is the difference from doing `extends ClassLoader` and `extends URLClassLoader` in your example?

Comment: The reason is to simplify the loading of classes. Of course you can do that without using the URLClassLoader. Then you have to implement Resolving / Loading of classes (how will your class loader load byte code for class X?)

Comment: I mean I don't understand what is the difference of your code to my code in relation to "Static Variable Isolation"?

Comment: Briefly: your class loader returns *the same* class instance as the context class loader. There is no isolation, because this is the same class instance: the same place in memory, the same static members, etc. To reach isolation, don't delegate to another class loader, but load classes directly, "by your own hands". Then you will get 2 different class instance with completely independent static members. I added more details to my answer above. You class loader is just a "short cut" for context class loader. It provides absolutely the same results as the context class loader.

Comment: My actual classloader code is `public class  MyClassloader extends ClassLoader {
 public MyClassloader() throws IOException {
  super(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
 }
}` Can you point out how this is different from your example?
And how this is not delegating as opposed to your example.

Comment: The difference is huge. In your constructor you set parent to the context class loader to the thread context class loader. Now look at the implementation of ClassLoader.loadClass(). The most important lines there the following once: if `(parent != null) { ... c = parent.loadClass(name, false); } else {`. Means, your `MyClassloader` *doesn't load* classes, it just **delegates** to its parent. And this parent you set to the thread context class loader. That's why your class loader returns absolutely the same as the context class loader.

Comment: But in my case it is *completely* different. I don't set any parent class loader and thus I don't delegate to the thread context class loader. My class loader performs all the "hard work" by itself. That's why it loads its *own* instance of the request class and that's why this instance is different from what the thread context class loader loads.

Comment: @mentallurg, I totally agree with your concept and explanation. But when I tested your piece of code, somehow the static variable of the 2 classes are reflecting the change made to ststic variable of other loaded class. Can you plz comment why ?

Comment: @Vishwanath: If we do a little bit debugging, we will see, that both have the same parent class loader. Which means, when we create MyIndependentClassLoader, we should set parent class loader to null, as a 2nd parameter in the super constructor.