# Do different spring application contexts share static variables

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Let's say there are 2 application Contexts in a spring-boot java app, namely ctx1 and ctx2.

In bean1 (inside ctx1), do
StaticClassX.setValue(100);

In bean2 (inside ctx2), do
StaticClassX.setValue(999);

Will the change in value of static attribute Value of StaticClassX by bean2 be reflected in bean1 ?

What will be the value of following expression ?
In bean1 (inside ctx1), do
StaticClassX.getValue();

Is there any way so as to keep static fields different in 2 contexts in same java app ?

Comment: Might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57642022/static-variable-isolation-with-custom-class-loader

Answer (score 1):

Changes to a static attribute in one Spring Boot application context won't affect another context.
Changes made to Value in bean2 won't be reflected in bean1.

Each application context manages its own set of bean instances, including static fields.

Comment: ... because each app has its own classloader.

Comment: But as mentioned in the question, app is only one. Same app (one java process) is having two contexts.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the classloader. If two contexts use different classloaders, every class created there will have it's own set of static variables.

Spring itself allows both. Application Context extends [DefaultResourceLoader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/DefaultResourceLoader.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.ClassLoader)), where you can specify the classloader to use.

In opposite to a JEE/EJB containers it is unusual to create different class loaders for different Spring contexts inside a single application. But it is possible, see the first link below.

Some Links:

- [Loading Spring context with specific classloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660115/loading-spring-context-with-specific-classloader) (stackoverflow)
- [Multiple Hierarchical Contexts in Spring Boot](https://dev.to/__nikolamicic21/multiple-hierarchical-contexts-in-spring-boot-25nf)
- [Java Spring multiple ApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862681/java-spring-multiple-applicationcontext) (stackoverflow)
- [Running Multiple Spring Boot Apps in the Same JVM](https://www.davidtanzer.net/david%27s%20blog/2015/04/01/running-multiple-spring-boot-apps-in-the-same-jvm.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question - yes. (This contradicts John's answer.)

```
class MultipleContextsTest {

    public Random rnd = new Random();

    public class Beanie {
        private static int baby;
        private int other = rnd.nextInt();

        public static void setBaby(int i) {
            baby = i;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("[baby=%s, other=%s]", baby, other);
        }
    }

    @Test
    void multipleContextsWithOwnBeanInstanceButBeanClassHasStaticAttributeShouldShareTheStaticAttributeValue() {
        var context1 = new GenericApplicationContext();
        registerBean(context1);
        context1.refresh();

        var context2 = new GenericApplicationContext();
        registerBean(context2);
        context2.refresh();

        System.out.println("after registration");
        System.out.format("from context1: %s\n", context1.getBean(Beanie.class.getCanonicalName(), Beanie.class));
        System.out.format("from context2: %s\n", context2.getBean(Beanie.class.getCanonicalName(), Beanie.class));

        context1.getBean(Beanie.class.getCanonicalName(), Beanie.class).setBaby(42);
        System.out.println("after setting context1 bean static value to 42");
        System.out.format("from context1: %s\n", context1.getBean(Beanie.class.getCanonicalName(), Beanie.class));
        System.out.format("from context2: %s\n", context2.getBean(Beanie.class.getCanonicalName(), Beanie.class));

        context2.getBean(Beanie.class.getCanonicalName(), Beanie.class).setBaby(43);
        System.out.println("after setting context2 bean static value to 43");
        System.out.format("from context1: %s\n", context1.getBean(Beanie.class.getCanonicalName(), Beanie.class));
        System.out.format("from context2: %s\n", context2.getBean(Beanie.class.getCanonicalName(), Beanie.class));
    }

    private void registerBean(GenericApplicationContext context) {
        var bean = new Beanie();
        var beanFactory = ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).getBeanFactory();
        beanFactory.registerSingleton(bean.getClass().getCanonicalName(), bean);
    }
}
```

sample run output:

```
after registration
from context1: [baby=0, other=266921875]
from context2: [baby=0, other=84225298]
after setting context1 bean static value to 42
from context1: [baby=42, other=266921875]
from context2: [baby=42, other=84225298]
after setting context2 bean static value to 43
from context1: [baby=43, other=266921875]
from context2: [baby=43, other=84225298]
```

Comment: Your test is invalid. You're using the same class loader to instantiate the bean. In reality, each app has its own classloader, which means that the statics are distinct.

Comment: @user207421 I don't understand what you mean by "each app". My doubt is regarding same app having 2 application contexts. Each context is having a bean. And these 2 beans share same static variable. In this case, will the update by 1 bean affect the value in another bean ? Is it possible for you to share a small code to explain the concept ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Andrew do you see any way so as to keep static fields separate in 2 different contexts ?