# Singleton with multiple ClassLoaders

Tags: java, singleton, classloader

In one of the interview I got asked about to how to make sure single object is present of a Singleton class when used with multiple classloaders.I followed this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156840/singleton-class-with-several-different-classloaders) but I couldn't understand how we should invoke the `getClass()`. As there is no information about it in the answer and as well as in the [link](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java-simply-singleton.html?page=2) provided in the answer.
 I am new to classloaders and things aren't that clear for me. I have tried the code and tried multiple combination but every time I am getting two instance instead of one.

```
package com.design_pattern;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class SIngletonPattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DatabaseConnection databaseConnection = DatabaseConnection.getDatabaseConnection();

        ClassLoader classLoader = SIngletonPattern.class.getClassLoader();
        System.out.println(classLoader);
        //Class classs = classLoader.getClass().forName(DatabaseConnection.class.getName());

        Class classs = DatabaseConnection.getClass(DatabaseConnection.class.getName());

        System.out.println(classs.getName());
        Constructor[] declaredConstructors = classs.getDeclaredConstructors();
        DatabaseConnection db2 = null;
        for (Constructor d:declaredConstructors) {
            d.setAccessible(true);
            db2 = (DatabaseConnection) d.newInstance();
        }

        if(db2 == null){
            System.out.println("null");
        }else{
            System.out.println(databaseConnection == db2);
        }

    }

}

class DatabaseConnection implements Serializable {

    private static volatile DatabaseConnection databaseConnection;

    private DatabaseConnection() {
        System.out.println("Instance created");
    }


    public static DatabaseConnection getDatabaseConnection() {
        System.out.println("getInstance()");
        if (databaseConnection == null) {
            synchronized (DatabaseConnection.class) {
                if (databaseConnection == null) {
                    databaseConnection = new DatabaseConnection();
                }
            }
        }
        return databaseConnection;
    }

    protected Object readResolve() {
        return databaseConnection;
    }

    public static Class getClass(String classname)
            throws ClassNotFoundException {
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        if(classLoader == null)
            classLoader = DatabaseConnection.class.getClassLoader();
        return (classLoader.loadClass(classname));
    }

}
```

Comment: When loading the same code with different class loaders, you will get different `Class`es that live in there own class loader.

Comment: java using the `Parent Delegation Model` for the different levels of class Loaders. Maybe this can help you https://programmer.help/blogs/jvm-series-parent-delegation-model-for-java-class-loading-mechanism.html

Comment: @dan1st thats what I don't want as I want to make my class singleton

Comment: You could try to save the object the main thread or utilize something else in the default library as the default library is the same in all class loaders.

Comment: @dan1st serialization part is not having issue classloader part is having issue