# System property in java

Tags: java, properties, jvm

I want to know if System.setProperty in java will cause the property to be set for the entire JVM.So if I set this property in a method will that be set for the entire JVM in a weblogic server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scope of the Java System Properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908903/scope-of-the-java-system-properties)

Comment: The short answer is yes ... assuming that you are really talking about just one JVM and not multiple JVMs.  Read the linked Q&A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> YES

java.lang.System#setProperty source code:

```
public static String setProperty(String key, String value) {
    checkKey(key);
    SecurityManager sm = getSecurityManager();
        if (sm != null) {
        sm.checkPermission(new PropertyPermission(key,
        SecurityConstants.PROPERTY_WRITE_ACTION));
    }

    return (String) props.setProperty(key, value);
}
```

and `props` is only a private static member in `java.lang.System`.

```
private static Properties props;
```

So, `java.lang.System#setProperty` and `java.lang.System#getProperty` are just normal static methods. Change the `props` will affect the whole JVM.