# Java System.setProperty(...); -> set trustStore path

Tags: java, jboss

I have set this system property in my web application:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:/Path/To/My/Cacerts/cacerts");
```

and then I have deployed this web application at a JBoss Server.
My question now would be if this setting is now for the whole JBoss Server and therefore for the whole applications deployed at JBoss or only for my web application?

Comment: That sets the property only for that process.  [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908903/scope-of-the-java-system-properties)

Comment: Is it possible to override this property setting in JBoss?

Comment: @user3318489 what is your JBoss version?

Comment: It is for the entire JVM in which the application is deployed, *if* it is set in time, i.e. before any default `SSLContexts` are created. This is almost certainly not the correct way to behave in a Web container.

Comment: I use JBoss 7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this setting is only for your web application were you have set property trust store.