# Is there anything in Java to to change the scope of system properties to WAR?

Tags: java

I have a WAR where a nasty library does things like `System.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory", ...)`, which breaks the web server container, since the latter depends on the value of the same property (details [here](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/3339)).

Before going through the tons of code misbehaving like that (yes, it's not even factorised), I'd like to check if there is some tool (eg, a special class loader) able to maintain WAR-level scope for at least writeable properties, so that these changes would remain in my web application and wouldn't interfere with the web container or other WARs.

Comment: A war built on what framework?

Comment: @Compass, how is that relevant? Eventually, it's standard WAR under Tomcat or Jetty. Anyway, it's an API built with Spring + Maven.

Comment: Can you file a bug report with the developer of that misbehaving library? Or, if it's open source, fix it yourself?

Comment: @Robert, legacy code, the developer has moved to someting else years ago. I'm able to fix it myself, but it implies rummaging through tens of files having that copy/pasted bad code.

Comment: There is a lesson here: When using system properties, choose a distinct property name.  For example, qualify the property name with the name of the package that uses it: "my.framework.compressStrings" instead of just "compressStrings".

Comment: @ThomasBitonti not really. `javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory` is pretty standard, you're supposed to use it if you want to change the XML parser to be used system-wide, but it should be changed from command line parameters or JVM config files, NOT hardwired in the code. Moreover, I know this and also your suggestion about naming app properties, the problem is there are pretty bad programmers out of my control.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Hardwiring an assignment to the property is the real problem.  That is bad code.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that I am aware of that can be used to narrow the scope of system properties.

There is a lot of related information here:
[Scope of the Java System Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908903/scope-of-the-java-system-properties)

Comment: Thanks, I had already read seen that and it's pretty clear those properties are on a per JVM instance level.