# How to avoid refresh ssl information for multiple https soap web services client in Java?

Tags: java, ssl, soap, https, wsdl

I got a java web application and this has two https soap web service clients:

```
https://product.com?wsdl
https://sales.com?wsdl
```

Each webservice has its own java class such as Product.java and Sales.java. Each class has its own implementation about how to invoke the web service entering the information like trustStore, trustStorePassword, keyStore, keyStorePassword, keyStoreType.
I'm understanding that these information are global for java. The classes are instaced using singleton. The thing is when the application invokes https://product.com?wsdl, it works. Then the app invokes https://sales.com?wsdl, it works. After that, the app invokes https://product.com?wsdl, it fails because the objects were instanced in singleton. Besides, the trustore and keystore information were not refreshed according to specific webservice. So in order to make it works is adding the code to refresh the trustore and keystore information before invokation. Other way is instacing without singleton but I think it's not a good idea because it can grow the ram memory.

Question:

1. Is it necessary to refresh the trustore and keystore information before invoking to a specefic webservice?
2. Are there inconvenients if I don't use singleton for instancing?

Added:

Product.java

```
public class Products {
    private static Products instance = null;
    public ProductsWS webServiceProduct = null;
    ...
    ...

    protected Products() {
        
        try{
            KeyManager[] keyManager = this.getKeyManagers(productKeyStore, productKeyStorePassword);
            TrustManager[] trustManager = this.getTrustManagers(productTrustStore, productTrustStorePassword);
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(keyManager, trustManager, null);
            HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) { return true; }
            };
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
                        
            QName qname = new QName("http://product.net/", "ProductsWSService");
            ProductsWSService productsWSService = new ProductsWSService(new URL(productUrl),qname);
            webServiceProduct = productsWSService.getProductsWSPort();
            System.out.println("Connection succeded");
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
    
    public static Products getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new Products();
        }
        return instance;
                
    }

    public String getProductName(int number) {
        if (number==1)
          return "Radio";
        else
          return "Television";
    }
    
}
```

Sales.java

```
public class Sales {
    private static Sales instance = null;
    public SalesWS webServiceSale = null;
    ...
    ...

    protected Sales() {
        
        try{
            KeyManager[] keyManager = this.getKeyManagers(saleKeyStore, saleKeyStorePassword);
            TrustManager[] trustManager = this.getTrustManagers(saleTrustStore, saleTrustStorePassword);
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(keyManager, trustManager, null);
            HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) { return true; }
            };
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
                        
            QName qname = new QName("http://sale.net/", "SalesWSService");
            SalesWSService salesWSService = new SalesWSService(new URL(productUrl),qname);
            webServiceProduct = salesWSService.getSalesWSPort();
            System.out.println("Connection succeded");
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
    
    public static Sales getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new Sales();
        }
        return instance;
                
    }

    public String getSaleDate(int number) {
        if (number==1)
          return "2023-01-01";
        else
          return "2023-02-01";
    }
    
}
```

Client.java

```
public class Client {

    protected Client() {    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Products clientProduct = Products.getInstance();
        String name = clientProduct.getProductName(1); // It works
        Sales saleProduct = Sales.getInstance();
        String date = saleProduct.getSaleDate(1); // It works
        name = clientProduct.getProductName(1); // It fails because the objects were instanced in singleton. 
        //Besides, the trustore and keystore information were not refreshed according to specific webservice
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, to understand your problem you need to post a minimum reproducible code sample so we can reproduce your problem and give you a solution.

Comment: I added the code to help to the text explanation

Comment: webServiceProduct = salesWSService.getSalesWSPort();

This should be webServiceSale = salesWSService.getSalesWSPort(); ?

Comment: A correct implementation of an [X509ExtendedTrustManager](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/X509ExtendedTrustManager.html) can select the certificate/key alias in the keystore for each HTTPS connection.

Comment: I checked the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908903/scope-of-the-java-system-properties about the scope of Java system properties and there's a reply where it says that system properties are per virtual machine. I uploaded the java web application on two wildfly's with different ports on same server. The results were that java system properties weren't shared so that's the goal I wanted to come